# How to configure backoff specifically on DLT topic

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm setting up non-blocking retries for my project using spring-kafka where in a failure scenario, a message goes from **main-topic** -> **retry-topic-0** -> **retry-topic-1** -> **retry-topic-n** ... -> **DLT**. On getting to the DLT and with the `ALWAYS_RETRY_ON_ERROR` strategy, the messages are forwarded back to the DLT topic and retried immediately.

On getting to the DLT, the behaviour I want to achieve is to retry till success on the DLT but with a backoff. For more context, I'm making use of the RetryTopicConfiguration builder and have set an exponential backoff on the builder (*which I understand only applies up until the message is forwaded to the DLT*). I've also set a separate dlt handler method on the builder i.e. `*.dltHandlerMethod(beanName, methodName)`.

The **question again is** seeing the default strategy on the DLT is to **ALWAYS_RETRY_ON_ERROR**, how can I set a backoff for messages that will be retried till success on the DLT topic. Can I make use of the `KafkaConsumerBackOffManager`?